# Are all fixed capital public goods?

Tags: microeconomics, consumption, public-goods

fixed capital: any kind of real or physical capital (fixed asset) that is not used up in the production of a product

public goods: goods that are non-rival and non-excludable in consumption

Both of the terms above seemed like they are talking about something similar so can I say that fixed capital all belong to the category of public goods?

Comment: No, they are not the same. Fixed capital can be excludable for example.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @BBKing, just to put it here as an answer: if we go back to your two definitions you can find quiet easily some counter examples. Let's take a firm, which uses a machine as capital. Let's assume also that this machine can only be used by one man at a time. Do you think this machine is a non-excludable / non-rival good ?